# Easier TFS Build Definition Update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I am new to a company which uses TFS as a source manager.  Currently when we make a new branch we create a copy of an old Build, then manually go in and edit all the workspace file paths and process definitions to reflect the new version(ie: if it was a copy of a 1.2.0 build, we go in and manually replace all the 1.2.0's with 1.3.0's)

Since we have ~70 folders and ~150 required processes to build, this gets rather tiring, time comsuming, and is error prone.  I've read that there is an API for TFS you can use- Is there a custom script I could write to replace all the old version #'s with the new ones?

- Also, under 'Workspace' its not too bad because you can copy it into notepad and do a 'ctrl+h' to replace it- it's really the processes that are killing it.

-Thank you, Kurtis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest you look at installing TFS Power tools.  It has a clone feature for build definitions that makes this very easy to do.  I don't know why it isn't built in, but the power tools are really great.

Power tools for TFS 2010 -
 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

For 2010 you might need this one instead, but you should check both out -   http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16bafc63-0f20-4cc3-8b67-4e25d150102c

Comment: Awesome! Even better, I don't have to write anything!
I will talk to my boss about approving this extension for us to use, thank you very much.